# What is the difference between "He was good at Geography" and "He is poor in Geography"?

Tags: prepositions

Why it can't be "He is poor at Geography"

Comment: What makes you think that "poor at geography" is not OK? Can you provide some information about how you deduced this?

Comment: If it is "He is poor in English" ( in reference to English Subject)

Comment: In fact 'He is bad at Geography' sounds more natural to me. (Br Eng)

Answer (score 2):

Just as verbs call for certain types of complements, so can adjectives.

Adjective **poor** [tends to want](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+poor+at%2Cis+poor+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20poor%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20poor%20in%3B%2Cc0) **in**, not **at**.

As you can see from the chart, "poor at" is not an impossibility, but usage strongly favors "in".

The same preference for "in" is found with the adverb, **do poorly *in*** being favored over **do poorly *at***.

Comment: I have to caution that I think that Ngrams is probably extremely misleading, because *poor in* can be used in multiple senses (e.g. [*they were poor in land*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22poor+in+land%22)) but *poor at* only has the one sense of "bad at".  Also, *poor in* is probably inflated by the very many references to [the poor in spirit](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+5:3) mentioned in the Bible.  When it comes to skill at a task, *poor at* sounds much more natural to me.

Comment: According to NGram, **poor at languages** and **poor at maths** are both more common than the **in** versions, whereas for english and geography the **in** versions are more frequent. The actual counts are so low, though, that they don't prove anything, other than that people seem to consider both forms acceptable.

Comment: This ngram (*do poorly in vs at*) addresses the objection that the results are skewed by biblical quotes; it shows the same strong preference for **in** (at least among those who write) and the meaning is clearly "not skilled in":  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+poorly+in%2Cdo+poorly+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20poorly%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20poorly%20at%3B%2Cc0